# Basic pointer question about allocating the address

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, printf, implicit-conversion

The following is my program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int a[][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    int (*ptr)[4] = a;

    for (int i=0; i< 4; i++){
        printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", ptr[i], (*ptr)[i]);
    }
    ++ptr;
    for (int i=0; i< 4; i++){
        printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", ptr[i], (*ptr)[i]);
    }

    printf("\n ------------------------------------------------");

    printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", &a[0][0], a[0][0]);
    printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", &a[0][1], a[0][1]);
    printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", &a[0][2], a[0][2]);
    printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", &a[0][3], a[0][3]);


    printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", &a[1][0], a[1][0]);
    printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", &a[1][1], a[1][1]);
    printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", &a[1][2], a[1][2]);
    printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", &a[1][3], a[1][3]);


    return 0;
}
```

Out is the Following.

```
 Address of -294704432, and value is  1
 Address of -294704416, and value is  2
 Address of -294704400, and value is  3
 Address of -294704384, and value is  4
 Address of -294704416, and value is  5
 Address of -294704400, and value is  6
 Address of -294704384, and value is  7
 Address of -294704368, and value is  8
 ------------------------------------------------
 Address of -294704432, and value is  1
 Address of -294704428, and value is  2
 Address of -294704424, and value is  3
 Address of -294704420, and value is  4
 Address of -294704416, and value is  5
 Address of -294704412, and value is  6
 Address of -294704408, and value is  7
 Address of -294704404, and value is  8
```

The sequence of addresses that were printed using simple **&** and static code is correct, where using the pointer I'm getting the correct value but the address of the 2nd-row element overwrites the address of the first row of the 2nd element.

Using the Pointer result is

```
 Address of -294704416, and value is  5
```

Overwrite the address of

```
 Address of -294704416, and value is  2
```

This is not affecting the operations I'm doing on the matrix but it is showing the same address how internally it is working, I'm looking for more explanation.

Comment: One tip: use `%p` with `printf` to print a pointer address.

Comment: The `%d` format is to print `int` values. `int` is typically 32 bits, while on a 64-bit system pointers are 64 bits. Mismatching `printf` specifier and value type leads to *undefined behavior*. As mentioned, to print a pointer use `%p`, but note that you really should cast the pointer to `void *` for it to be correct.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Are you confused because the 2 lines you mention, contain same address but different value? You are not printing the value at the address you print. Try to print like this: `printf("\n Address of (*ptr)[%d]) is %p, and value is  %d", i, (void*)&((*ptr)[i]), (*ptr)[i]);`

Answer (score 3):

You declared a two-dimensional array with two "rows" (that is the type of elements of the array is one-dimensional array `int[4]`)

```
int a[][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

So the pointer `ptr`

```
int (*ptr)[4] = a;
```

points to the first "row" of the array.

In this for loop

```
for (int i=0; i< 4; i++){
    printf("\n Address of %d, and value is  %d", ptr[i], (*ptr)[i]);
}
```

the expression `ptr[i]` has the type `int[4]` and used as an argument of the call of `printf` it is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `int *`.

So within the format string (in this call of printf and other calls of printf) you have to use the conversion specifier `p` instead of `d` to output pointers

```
printf("\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )ptr[i], (*ptr)[i]);
```

As the array has only two "rows" then the expression `ptr[i]` in the for loop accesses memory beyond the array (for `i` equal to `3`) that results in undefined behavior.

In any case the outputted addresses does not correspond to the addresses (except the first outputted address when `i` is equal to `0`) of outputted elements of rows.

It seems what you need is the following

```
printf("\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )( ( *ptr ) + i ), (*ptr)[i]);
```

The expression `( void * )( ( *ptr ) + i )` points to the i-th element of the given "row".

That is your code in main will look like

```
    int a[][4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    int( *ptr )[4] = a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )( ( *ptr ) +i ), ( *ptr )[i] );
    }

    ++ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )( ( *ptr ) + i ), ( *ptr )[i] );
    }

    printf( "\n ------------------------------------------------" );

    printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )&a[0][0], a[0][0] );
    printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )&a[0][1], a[0][1] );
    printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )&a[0][2], a[0][2] );
    printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )&a[0][3], a[0][3] );


    printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )&a[1][0], a[1][0] );
    printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )&a[1][1], a[1][1] );
    printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )&a[1][2], a[1][2] );
    printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )&a[1][3], a[1][3] );
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

dynamic loop
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )( ( *ptr ) +i ), ( *ptr )[i] );
 }

// increased pointer
++ptr;
// again dynamic loop
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )( ( *ptr ) +i ), ( *ptr )[i] );
 }
This is same as following static code of address and values
printf( "\n Address of %p, and value is  %d", ( void * )&a[0][0], a[0][0] );

Using the pointer address of 2nd array element of 1st column and in 2nd column is the same

Comment: I checked your code, and it is working fine. Thank you. I will explore more.

Comment: Can you please explain ( void * )( ( *ptr ) +i )

why + i here as we already increasing i in the for loop.

Comment: @GayatriP The expression *ptr gives either the "row" 0 or the "row" 1 of the two-dimensional array.  It is equivalent to ptr[0]. That is the expression *ptr is one-dimensional array  of the type int[4]. Used in the expression *ptr + i  it is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array (row). In fact you &ptr[0][i]